# MySQL Import - Preserve ID Numbers

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails application that creates an invoice and populates the invoice.approver_id from a table called adusers.

We have a batch script running nightly to populate the adusers table from an AD csv dump file.

During the auto MySQL import, how do I retain the adusers IDs so my invoice records retain the correct approver_id (aduser.id)?

Comment: Are you dealing with an autoincrement field?  If not, why not just explicitly insert the ids as you read them?

Comment: If it's an insert statement, you just supply the value. MySQL will use that if it isn't already in use.

Comment: Yes, it is auto-incremented.  The script drops the adusers table and recreates it, so the ids can change daily.  I think I need to re-write the script so it only inserts NEW adusers, thus retaining the existing adusers and their ids. But, that might not work, either, because some adusers can change last names (marriage/divorce, for instance).  I think what I will end up doing is pull the username from the adusers table instead of the id and save that in the invoice table so it retains historical data there. Thanks all.  Just had to talk it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a block to your create method you can forcibly set the primary id there.  For example:

```
Product.create!(:name => row[:name]) {|p| p.id = row[:id]})
```